# How to read special characters

Tags: python

I am getting a value of column from database like below:

```
`;;][@+©
```

When I am reading this in my Python code this is giving below error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 7: invalid start byte
```

Then I tried below code but not working:

```
unicode(' `;;][@+©', 'utf-8')
```

Now how can I solve this problem?

Comment: figure the encoding of rhe data that you are receiving from your database. We _can not_ guess what it is...it is _your_ database....and obviously it is not utf-8....

Answer (score 3):

First, read [this article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). The string you have is encoded in *some* encoding, but not [UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). The reason we can tell it's not UTF8 is that the 7th byte 0xa9 (= 169) isn't in the range 0-127 (ASCII), but isn't preceded by a leading byte.

So the trick is to work out what encoding it is. We've got a hint: the encoding needs to represent the byte 0xa9 as the glyph ©. I'd guess that it's either the [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encodings because they're very common, and looking up A9 in the grid (character encodings are essentially the same as playing battleships) gives the copyright sign in both.

```
>>> unicode(' `;;][@+©')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> unicode(' `;;][@+©', 'latin-1')
u' `;;][@+\xc2\xa9'
>>> unicode(' `;;][@+©', 'cp1252')
u' `;;][@+\xc2\xa9'
```